# My Pakistani passport is going to expire in 1 September 2024. Can I go Pakistan in April and come back to the UK in May? I have a valid NIC card

Tags: uk, passports, pakistani-citizens, uk-residents

My Pakistani passport has less than 7 months. But I need to go to Pakistan in April and come back to the UK in May. Can I travel with less than 6 months on my passport?

Comment: What proof of permission to enter the UK do you have? Is it a stamp in the passport expiring in a few months?

Comment: What is your immigration status in the UK? If you’re a visitor, your passport should be valid for the whole of your stay.

Comment: I have BRP CARD

Comment: @Farwa Your question is unclear. Is it about passport validity for travelling to Pakistan, or for returning to UK? Or both?

Comment: For those wondering, a BRP is a Biometric Resident Permit https://www.gov.uk/biometric-residence-permits

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can freely travel as long as both your passport and visa/residence card are valid during your travel duration, which you said are valid. You should not travel with invalid visa AND passport. The airline would not let you check in with an invalid passport. Hope it helps.